# Location BroadcastReceiver App Crashes if minTime is set to any other value than 0

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, locationmanager, android-location

I am trying to write a data sharing application which will run 24/7 and keep on sharing data whenever user travels more than 650 meters in 3 minutes.

Error is that the app stops unexpectedly if I pass any non-zero value lets say 18000 in minTime rather than passing 0. Works absolutely fine if minTime = 0.

Here is my code..

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.agentbackgroundbroadcastreciever;

    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.location.Criteria;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationReceiver.class);
            LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            long minTime = 18000;
            float minDistance = 650;
            String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;   //GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER

            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);


            PendingIntent launchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

            manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, minDistance, launchIntent);   ////Crashes if I put 18000 instead of 0 in minTime here

        //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Came here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

LocationReceiver.java

```
package com.example.agentbackgroundbroadcastreciever;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(intent != null)
        {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            Location location = (Location) bundle.get(LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Received"+location.getLatitude()+"   "+location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //      DataSharing data=new DataSharing();
    //      data.sendSms(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), new java.util.Date());
        }
    }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.agentbackgroundbroadcastreciever"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name="LocationReceiver">

   </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.agentbackgroundbroadcastreciever.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I could not figure out what is going wrong. Help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

if (LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED)) {
}

instead of "if(intent != null)"